How to get the keycloak_flutter example app to work
I am one of those people who need to implement keycloak in a Dart/Flutter web app.  To get a feel for how it works I used the keycloak_flutter package (see https://pub.dev/packages/keycloak_flutter ) and tried the example that is presented there.
I needed to change it slightly because of some deprecated widgets, but managed to get it running.
However ... although it seems to work, it does not really.  Clicking de Log-in button correctly jumps to the keycloak log-in screen and it correctly returns to my app after entering proper credentials.  Clicking log-in again immediately returns to my app, suggesting that keycloak sees the user as being logged in already.  Likewise, clicking the log-out button indeed shows the keycloak panel that asks for confirmation.
Where it does NOT work is in the sample app itself.  It should - upon log-on - retrieve the userinfo and show that on screen.  But it does not.  I noticed it retrieves the user info if it receives an OnAuthSuccess event from keycloak.  But what I see happening is that keycloak invariably returns an OnAuthLogout event!  Even after an apparent correct log-in.  I never get OnAuthSuccess.  I only get OnAuthLogout  (and an OnReady at the very beginning of the app).
I'm using Keycloak 26.0.2.  This package also requires a javascript file keycloak.js, which I downloaded and implemented as mentioned in the read-me.
I was wondering if somebody can help me in detecting where I go wrong.  Is there some Keycloak setting I may have overlooked or set wrong (although I found that in the cases where I had something not right, Keycloak usually protests with an error-message.)  To rule out URL problems in keycloak I set all URI's to '*' for the time being.  As far as I can tell users, and roles are set correctly.
Maybe version errors between Keycloak (26.0.2) and the package (0.0.21) with its keycloak.js file?  Maybe still something wrong in the keycloak set-up?
(I incidentally also tried the other Keycloak package (called flutter_keycloak), but that does not work at all, give an error in an XMLHttpRequest).
